# My requires doesn't work with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I want to test my library but when I want to require its file in test class and run it with `phpunit filename.php` I get error like this:

```
Warning: require_once(>>>path to file<<<): failed to open stream: No such
file or directory in >>>file with test<<< on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required >>>path to file<<<
(include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in >>>file with test<<< on line 3
```

*As you can see I use xampp.*

Of course when I don't run it with phpunit but through browser - all imports works great (I always use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get absolute path).

*without my require simple test like `assertTrue(true)` works without any problems.

Comment: The error message tells you that your `include_path` is configured to include files from the current working dir and the PEAR directory. In other words, PHPUnit will try to include your test files from the PEAR directory or whatever directory PHPUnit was invoked in. Consider adding a phpunit.xml with proper configurations to a bootstrap file. See https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Comment: I'm afraid that I tried to add to include_path `C:\xampp\htdocs` but it didn't help. Now I moved all library files and dependencies to `pear` folder and it works but this is escape from the problem